# Duplicate identifier error in tidyr

Tags: r, tidyr

I am using `tidyr` from `R` and am running into an issue when using the `spread()` command with duplicate identifiers.

Here is a mock example that illustrates the problem:

```
X = data.frame(name=c("Eric","Bob","Mark","Bob","Bob","Mark","Eric","Bob","Mark"),
               metric=c("height","height","height","weight","weight","weight","grade","grade","grade"),
               values=c(6,5,4,120,118,180,"A","B","C"),
               stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

tidyr::spread(X,metric,values)
```

So when I run this command I get the following error:

```
Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (4, 5)
```

which makes sense why its an error because Bob is recorded twice for weight. It's actually nota  mistake because Bob did have his weight recorded twice. What I would like to be able to do is have run the command and have it it give me back the following:

```
name height weight grade
Eric     6     NA     A
Bob      5    120     B
Bob      5    118     B
Mark     4    180     C
```

Is spread not the command I should be using to accomplish this? And if there isn't an easy solution is there a simple way to remove the record with lowest weight for duplicates when running the `spread()` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After making unique identifiers, which can be done by making a new variable representing the index within each group, you can use `fill` to fill the second "Bob" row with a duplicate value for "height" and "grade".

You can remove the index variable at the end via `select`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

X %>%
     group_by(name, metric) %>%
     mutate(row = row_number() ) %>%
     spread(metric, values) %>%
     fill(grade, height) %>%
     select(-row)

# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   name [3]
   name grade height weight
  <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>
1   Bob     B      5    120
2   Bob     B      5    118
3  Eric     A      6   <NA>
4  Mark     C      4    180
```

To `filter` to the maximum value of each `name`/`metric` group:

```
X %>%
     group_by(name, metric) %>%
     filter(values == max(values)) %>%
     spread(metric, values)

# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   name [3]
   name grade height weight
* <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>
1   Bob     B      5    120
2  Eric     A      6   <NA>
3  Mark     C      4    180
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to say just remove the one with the smallest value

Comment: You can remove things via a grouped `filter`, choosing only the maximum value of each "name"/"metric" combination.

Comment: You can remove the smallest values with this
```X %>%
    group_by(name, metric) %>%
    mutate(row = row_number(),
           least = min(row)) %>%
    spread(metric, values) %>%
    fill(grade, height) %>% 
    filter(row == least) %>% 
    select(-row, -least)```